# Why doesn't converted script calculate the same as original when converting from V2 to V4 in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script-v4

When converting a script from V2 to V4 in Pinescript, it doesn't appear to be calculating the same.

V2:

```
study(title = "POC bands 2.0", shorttitle="POCB", overlay=true)
resCustom = input(title="Timeframe", type=resolution, defval="240")
Length = input(6, minval=1)
xPrice = security(tickerid, resCustom, hlc3)
xvnoise = abs(xPrice - xPrice[1])
nfastend = 0.666
nslowend = 0.0645
nsignal = abs(xPrice - xPrice[Length])
nnoise = sum(xvnoise, Length)
nefratio = iff(nnoise != 0, nsignal / nnoise, 0)
nsmooth = pow(nefratio * (nfastend - nslowend) + nslowend, 2) 
nAMA = nz(nAMA[1]) + nsmooth * (xPrice - nz(nAMA[1]))
basis = nAMA
atr = ema(tr,11)
upper = basis[3] + (atr*3)
lower = basis[3] - (atr*3)

plot(basis, color=blue)
plot(upper, color=blue)
plot(lower, color=blue)
```

V4:

```
study(title = "POC bands 2.0", shorttitle="POCB", overlay=true)
resCustom = input(title="Timeframe", type=input.resolution, defval="240")
Length = input(6, minval=1)
xPrice = security(syminfo.tickerid, resCustom, hlc3)
xvnoise = abs(xPrice - xPrice[1])
nAMA = 0.0
nfastend = 0.666
nslowend = 0.0645
nsignal = abs(xPrice - xPrice[Length])
nnoise = sum(xvnoise, Length)
nefratio = iff(nnoise != 0, nsignal / nnoise, 0)
nsmooth = pow(nefratio * (nfastend - nslowend) + nslowend, 2) 

nAMA := nz(nAMA[1]) + nsmooth * (xPrice - nz(nAMA[1]))
basis = nAMA
atr = ema(tr,11)
upper = basis[3] + (atr*3)
lower = basis[3] - (atr*3)

plot(basis, color=color.new(color.blue,0))
plot(upper, color=color.new(color.white,0))
plot(lower, color=color.new(color.white,0))
```

V2 are the blue bands with a red center and V4 are the white bands with a blue center.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because the security function has different default values for the bargaps and lookahead parameters between v2 and v4
With v4, both are set to false by default
With v2, probably one or both of them are set to true